# Higher and Lower Card game - Swift 4.2

Tags: swift, xcode, image, var, let

Keeping up with the Higher and lower card game, having problems with the next card not coming, whether pushing higher or lower button, the next card will not come, is there anything in the code I forgot or not seen? want to have only one life on this game. I can see that the game works when I press higher or lower button since I get alert message with score and gameover

```
var cards = [Card]()
var lives = 1 {
    didSet {
        self.liveLabel.text = "Lives: \(lives)"
    }
}
var score = 0 {
    didSet {
        self.scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(score)"
    }
}

var cardIndex  = 0
var cardValue = ""


@IBOutlet weak var liveLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var cardImageView: UIImageView!


@IBOutlet weak var lowButton: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var hiButton: UIButton!

let endPoint = "http://cards.davidneal.io/api/cards"

fileprivate func loadCardDeck() {

    lowButton.isEnabled = false
    hiButton.isEnabled = false

    let cardApi = CardAPIClient()
    cardApi.getCards(endPoint: endPoint) { (cardData) in

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.cards = cardData ?? [Card]()
            print(self.cards.count as Any)

            self.cards = self.suffle()

            self.lowButton.isEnabled = true
            self.hiButton.isEnabled = true
            self.cardValue = self.cards[0].value ?? ""
            self.setDisplayCard()
        }
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.lives = 1
    self.score = 0
    self.loadCardDeck()

}



@IBAction func lowButtonPress(_ sender: Any) {
    cardIndex += 1
    let nextCardValue = self.cards[cardIndex].value
    setDisplayCard()

    if   nextCardValue != self.cardValue {

        if !NextCardIsHigher(firstValue: self.cardValue, secondValue: nextCardValue!) {
            score += 1

        } else {
            lives -= 1
        }
    }
    self.cardValue = self.cards[cardIndex].value ?? ""

    checkGameOverReset()
}

fileprivate func resetLabels() {
    self.lives = 1
    self.score = 0
    self.cardIndex  = 0

    var suffle = self.suffle()
    self.cards = suffle
    suffle = [Card]()

    self.cardValue = self.cards[0].value ?? ""
    self.setDisplayCard()
}

fileprivate func checkGameOverReset() {
    if lives <= 0 {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Game Over", message: "Your score is \(score)", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { action in

            self.resetLabels()

        }))
        self.present(alert, animated: true)
    }
}

@IBAction func hiButtonPress(_ sender: Any) {
    cardIndex += 1
    let nextCardValue = self.cards[cardIndex].value ?? ""
    setDisplayCard()
    if   nextCardValue != self.cardValue {
        if NextCardIsHigher(firstValue: self.cardValue, secondValue: nextCardValue) {
            score += 1

        } else {
            lives -= 1
        }
    }
    self.cardValue = self.cards[cardIndex].value ?? ""

    checkGameOverReset()
}

func suitValue( suit: String)-> String {
    switch suit {
    case "spades" :
        return "S"
    case "diamonds":
        return "D"
    case "clubs":
        return "C"
    case "hearts":
        return "H"
    default:
        return ""
    }
}

func setDisplayCard() {
    let nextCardValue = self.cards[cardIndex].value ?? ""
    let nextCardSuit = self.cards[cardIndex].suit ?? ""
    let nextCardSuitShortdesc = self.suitValue(suit: nextCardSuit)
    let imageName = nextCardValue + nextCardSuitShortdesc 

    if let imgPat = Bundle.main.path(forResource: imageName, ofType: "png") {
        self.cardImageView.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imgPat)
    }
}


func NextCardIsHigher(firstValue: String, secondValue: String)-> Bool {
    var defaultReturn = false
    var firstString = ""
    var secondString = ""

    switch firstValue {
    case "A" :
        firstString = "1"
    case "J" :
        firstString = "11"
    case "K" :
        firstString = "12"
    case "Q" :
        firstString = "13"
    default :
        firstString = firstValue
    }

    switch secondValue {
    case "A" :
        secondString = "1"
    case "J" :
        secondString = "11"
    case "K" :
        secondString = "12"
    case "Q" :
        secondString = "13"
    default :
        secondString = secondValue
    }

    ( Int(secondString)! >  Int(firstString)! ) ? (defaultReturn = true) : (defaultReturn = false)
    return defaultReturn
}


func suffle()-> [Card] {

    var shuffled = [Card]();
    for _ in 0..<self.cards.count {
        let rand = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.cards.count)))
        shuffled.append(self.cards[rand])
        self.cards.remove(at: rand)
    }
    return shuffled
}
```

}

Comment: Unrelated but you can replace the body of your `s(h)uffle` method with `return self.cards.shuffled()`

Comment: Add a breakpoint to `setDisplayCard()` and check what value is missing

Comment: Thanks Tal Cohen, I had to put the image folder to the new group folder, my mistake. that was it